# Send a push Notifications to users who have changed the password 30 days before

Tags: laravel, push-notification

This is my case:

In my database, I have a table `users`. The rows in the table also have a field `password_changed_at`. Now I would like to select all users where the `password_changed_at` field is older than 30 days and send a push notification But I'm stuck on how to do this with Carbon. My code now looks like this:

```php
public function passwordExpired() {

    $dateTime = new DateTime();
    $currentDateTime = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i');
    $users = User::where('password_changed_at', $currentDateTime)->get();

    // $user = $request->user();
    foreach ($users as $user) {

    $password_changed_at = new Carbon(($user->password_changed_at) ? $user->password_changed_at : "");

    if (Carbon::now()->diffInDays($password_changed_at) >= 30) {

        foreach ($password_changed_at as $password) 
        {
            // $user = $user->id;
            $user->notify(new ReminderPassword($user));

        $push = new PushNotification('apn');
        $push->setMessage([
            'aps' => [
                'alert' => 'Reminder for your password "'.$user->email.'"',
                'sound' => 'default',
                'badge' => $user->unreadNotifications->count()

            ],
            'extraPayLoad' => [
                'custom' => 'My custom data',
            ]
        ]);
        $push->setDevicesToken($user->deviceToken);
        $push->send();
        $feedback = $push->getFeedback();
        }
```

Comment: You have errors in the syntax: what if you remove `foreach ($password_changed_at as $password) {`? That is not necessary.

Comment: You should also set `password_change_at` as "date" in the User model. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `diffInDays` works the other way round (i.e. diffing an older day returns a negative value). See: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

So you can change your code like this:

```php
public function passwordExpired() {

$dateTime = new DateTime();
$currentDateTime = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i');
$users = User::where('password_changed_at', $currentDateTime)->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {

    $password_changed_at = new Carbon(
      ($user->password_changed_at) ? $user->password_changed_at : ""
    );

    // DiffIndays works the other way round:

    if ($password_changed_at->diffInDays(Carbon::now()) >= 30) {

        $user->notify(new ReminderPassword($user));

        $push = new PushNotification('apn');
        $push->setMessage([
            'aps' => [
              'alert' => 'Reminder for your password "' . $user->email . '"', 
              'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => $user->unreadNotifications->count() 
             ], 
             'extraPayLoad' => ['custom' => 'My custom data', ]
        ]);
        $push->setDevicesToken($user->deviceToken);
        $push->send();

        $feedback = $push->getFeedback();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

With `$users = User::where('password_changed_at', $currentDateTime)->get();` you selecting all users who has changed their date *today*, but you want select all users which has changed their password +30 days before.

So you can just select these with using a query scope. In your Users class add this:

```
class Users extends Authenticatable
{

    // ...

    public function scopePasswordOlderThan30Days(Builder $builder)
    {
        $expirationDate = Carbon::now()->subDays(30);

        return $builder->where('password_changed_at', '<=', $expirationDate);
    }
}
```

In your function use it like:

```
public function passwordExpired()
{
    $users = User::passwordOlderThan30Days()->get();

    $users->each(function(User $user) {
        // notify the user
    })
}
```